# git add --patch and yarn.lock

Tags: git, yarnpkg

> **TLDR:** how to git add --patch yarn.lock after various dependency changes?

Okay, this might be my sometimes messy workflow but I want to know all possible options before deciding if that's actually true

So I really like to sometimes rapidly move forward and then `git add --patch` my changes in contextual chunks/hunks as I see fit when I feel it's time to version my mess, and I prefer `git add --patch` recently anyway as I get to see my changes one by one while deciding consciously…
Only problem I came across so far is yarn.lock (I guess package-lock.json might be the same).

To get to the point, after messing around, changing various things, installing/removing dependencies, I decide e.g. one of those changes gets to be "official" now, I can easily pick all the desired changes related to this. But at this stage I might have installed/removed multiple dependencies, so yarn.lock has changed a lot and, contrary to package.json, I can't safely and easily pick just the updates I care about. Not without checking all changed packages in detail and figuring out their dependencies.
Or am I missing something?

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1776#issuecomment-297124714) using `git checkout -- yarn.lock` could be a way, so I would check out a former yarn.lock, but I would have to at least temporarily undo changes to package.json, than do my `yarn add/remove ..` so yarn.lock updates correctly, git everything, then redo my package.json/yarn.lock changes and continue my work.

Any other ways/proposals?